# Calculating a subspace of the kernel of product matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I do not know whether the following is correct:

Consider two matrices $A$ and $B$ and a vector $x$ (all of them with suitable dimensions) such that
$$
AB x = 0,
$$
i.e. $x$ belongs to the kernel of $AB$. I would like to calculate the subspace $x\in\mathcal{U}$ such that $AB x =0$ but $Bx \neq 0$.

Is then the following notation correct? or is there any more proper/standard way for such a subspace?

$$
\mathcal{U}= ker(AB) \setminus (ker(B) - {0})
$$

### EDIT

According to the comments, I cannot see why $\mathcal{U}$ would not be a subspace. Then I cannot compute a basis for $\mathcal{U}$. Is there then any systematic way for computing such a $\mathcal{U}$?

Comment: First of all, that won't be a subspace in general. But otherwise, yeah, that's what it is.

Comment: that is my problem, I cannot see why in general it is not a subspace. What would be the conditions for that? thanks

Comment: Not in general, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include $x=0$, then the following is a false proof that $\mathcal U$ is a subspace:
$$x \in \mathcal U \wedge y \in \mathcal U \implies ABx=0 \wedge ABy=0 \implies AB(x+y)=0 \implies x+y \in \mathcal U$$
$$c \text{ is a scalar } \wedge x \in \mathcal U \implies cABx=0 \implies AB(cx)=0 \implies cx \in \mathcal U$$
This is a false proof because if we have $Bx,By \neq 0$, this means $x,y \notin \text{ker}(B)$, but if we sum $x$ and $y$ together, it's entirely possible that $x+y \in \text{ker}(B)$, which would make $Bx+By=B(x+y)=0$ even if $x+y \neq 0$, so $x+y \notin \mathcal U$ in such a case and $\mathcal U$ is a subspace.

Thus, in order for the above proof to work, we need:
$$x,y \notin \text{ker}(B) \implies \left(x+y \notin \text{ker}(B) \vee x+y=0\begin{matrix}\\ \\ \end{matrix}\right)$$
Use material implication:
$$x,y \notin \text{ker}(B) \implies \left(x+y \in \text{ker}(B) \implies x+y=0\begin{matrix}\\ \\ \end{matrix}\right)$$
Combine the conditionals:
$$\left(x,y \notin \text{ker}(B) \wedge x+y \in \text{ker}(B)\begin{matrix}\\ \\ \end{matrix}\right) \implies x+y=0$$
I'll leave it up to you to show that this means $\text{ker}(B)=\{0\}$ or $B=\mathbf 0$. Good luck!

Therefore, we have two cases (NOTE: $V$ represents the whole vector space.):
$$B=\mathbf 0 \implies \mathcal U=\text{ker}(AB)-(\text{ker}(B)-\{0\})=\text{ker}(AB)-V+\{0\}=\{0\}$$
$$\text{ker}(B)=\{0\} \implies \mathcal U=\text{ker}(AB)-(\text{ker}(B)-\{0\})=\text{ker}(AB)-\emptyset=\text{ker}(AB)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me to understand what is going on for the general case! I have found it very illustrative! I am thinking a bit more about my particular case. I will come back once I have my next comment more clear.

Comment: in my particular case I am checking "infinitesimally rigid matrices", where their kernel stands for translations and rotations for some rigid structure. In my problem it is clear that $Bx=0$ stands for translations and $ABx=0$ for rotations (about the centroid of the structure) and translations. I am looking for all $x$ that provide only rotations (I believe that this is the subspace $\mathcal{U}$ I am looking for). I would say that, in my particular problem, in your answer I can safely consider that $x+y \notin ker(B)$, since the sum of rotations cannot produce a translation.

Comment: @noether Usually, translations are not linear transformations and can not be written as a matrix. Can you give the actual $A$ and $B$ values or examples of such?

Comment: You are right, sorry I was not more precise. In fact, what I am giving are vector velocities. $B$ is the transpose of an incidence matrix (with the corresponding Kronecker product) defining an infinitesimally minimally rigid "framework". The column vector of all $1$s is left eigenvector (for the eigenvalue 0) of the incidence matrix. If all the nodes' velocities $v_i$ in the framework have all the x (y and z) components equal then we have a  translation. Therefore $Bv = 0$ means that all the nodes have exactly the same velocity, i.e. there is a translation of the whole structure.

Comment: Now for $A$. Consider that $z_k$ is the relative position between two nodes corresponding to the edge $k$. In a rotation, all the $||z_k||^2$ are kept constant, but not $z_k$. The condition $z_k^T \dot z_k = 0$ needs to be satisfied in order to keep the norm $z_k$ constant. Define $A$ as the block diagonal matrix diag($z_1^T,\dots, z_n^T$). Note that $\dot z = Bv$, so in order to keep the norm of all the $z_k$, we have that $ABv = 0$, but we know that $Bv = 0$ defines only translations. This is why I am interested in such subspace $\mathcal{U}$ (if it exists ofc).

Comment: @noether At this point, I'm quite out of my depth here since I've never worked with "infinitesimally minimally rigid frameworks," but I'd just like to ask you to make sure that the sum of two rotations can not be a translation because it seems to be that if a graph rotates a little and then it rotates in a different way, then it can be in the same orientation it was in before but in a different place, which would be a translation.

Comment: @noether Also, is it possible that the sum of a rotation and translation could be in the kernel of $AB$ but not in the kernel of $B$? If so, then you could sum a rotation and a translation to get an element of $\mathcal U$ and then sum the opposite rotation and translation to get another element of $\mathcal U$, but when you sum those two vectors together, you get a translation, which is not in $\mathcal U$.

Comment: No worries, I understand that I am not the best explaining things and here it is difficult to define a lot of concepts. Thanks anyway for your interest in helping me! A rotation (about the centroid, aka 'spinning') never moves the centroid, therefore there is not translation. If there is a translation, then the centroid moves, so it is in the kernel of $B$. This is related about the motion of rigid bodies. We can move one rigid body from one position and orientation to another one, by just the combination of a translation + spinning (or at once by defining properly an axis of rotation).

Comment: mmm I will think further about your last comment, I believe is not possible what you say, but I am also tired now to find a rigorous proof of that.

Comment: Btw, I have a particular example for triangles and tetrahedrons where I can find explicitly such a space $x\in\mathcal{U}$ for only rotations about the centroid. Now I have to understand better if such a subspace that I have found explicitly can be written as in the main question.

Comment: @noether I am still a bit confused. Let's say you have $v$ as a rotation so $v \in \mathcal U$. You already told me that $\mathbf 1 \in \text{ker}(AB)$ because it is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$. Therefore, wouldn't we have $\mathbf 1+v \in \mathcal U$ because $$AB(1+v)=AB1+ABv=0+0=0 \\ B(1+v)=B1+Bv=0+Bv=Bv \neq 0$$ and $\mathbf 1-v \in \mathcal U$ because $$AB(1-v)=AB1-ABv=0-0=0 \\ B(1-v)=B1-Bv=0-Bv=-Bv \neq 0$$, but $(\mathbf 1+v)+(\mathbf 1-v)=2\mathbf 1 \in \text{ker}(B)$? If so, why is this not possible? Why can't we move the centroid AND spin the body in one vector?

Comment: You are right! since $1+v \notin ker(B)$, my expression in the question for looking for a subspace defining only rotations is not correct! Nevertheless we have that $1+v$ does not define a rotation about the centroid. It seems that what I am looking for is the following: $\mathcal{U} = P (ker (AB))$, where $P$ would be the orthogonal projection over $ker(B)$ (roughly speaking I am removing the translational component), e.g. $P(1+v) = P(1) + P(v) = 0 + v$, would you agree with that? would be this new $\mathcal{U}$ a subspace properly defined now?

Comment: @noether Yes, now I agree that $\mathcal U$ should be a subspace because you have removed the translation part, although I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: no worries, I have already proved that part. My problem was how to define such subspace. Thanks a lot for your really helpful discussion! I am not so used to algebra and I have learned something about it today :P

Comment: I'm glad I could help!